# Exim configuration SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined

Tags: exim

Cause change smtp server exim configured with smart host no longer sends mail with the following errors.
The command used is this

```
# exim -v webmaster@mydomain.com
From: Webmaster <webmaster@maydomain.com>
Subject: Test Email
This is a test email.
```

the errors returned are as follows:

```
SMTP|> MAIL FROM:<> SIZE=2952
  SMTP|> RCPT TO:<root@mydomain.com>
         will write message using CHUNKING
  SMTP+> BDAT 1929 LAST
  SMTP>> QUIT
  SMTP<< 451 4.0.0 Invalid from
  SMTP<< 502 5.5.1 Missing MAIL FROM command.
LOG: MAIN
  H=smtp-relay.brevo.com [1.179.115.1]: SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined end of data: 451 4.0.0 Invalid from
  SMTP<< 502 5.5.1 Missing RCPT TO command.
  SMTP(close)>>
cmdlog: '220:EHLO:250-:STARTTLS:220:EHLO:250-:AUTH:334:********:235:MAIL|:RCPT|:BDAT:QUIT:451:502:502'
LOG: MAIN
  == root@mydomain.com R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost defer (-45) H=smtp-relay.brevo.com [1.179.115.1]: SMTP error from remote mail server after pipelined end of data: 451 4.0.0 Invalid from
```

I haven't had the necessary support to solve the problem from the smtpserver vendor, so I'm asking you.

Thanks for the help